# Attribute 'profile' is not allowed to appear in element 'beans:bean'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Not sure what's happening here. My XML bean definition schema is using:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

The problematic bean in definition:

```
 <beans:bean profile="dev,qa,prod">
        <beans:bean parent="propertyConfigurer">
            <beans:property name="order" value="0"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="locations">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>classpath:messages.properties</beans:value>
                     <beans:value>classpath:common.properties</beans:value>
                    <beans:value>classpath*:META-INF/properties/local.properties</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
</beans:bean>
```

But, I'm getting:

```
 cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'profile' is not allowed to appear in element 'beans:bean'
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`profile` attribute must appear in `beans` element i.e.:

```
<beans:beans profile="qa" ... >
    <bean id="..." ...></bean>
</beans>
```

There can be multiple nested `beans` element:

```
<beans:beans>
    <bean id="..." ...></bean>
    <beans:beans profile="prod" ... >
        <bean id="..." ...></bean>
    </beans>
    <beans:beans profile="qa" ... >
        <bean id="..." ...></bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```